# How to edit or delete a question in Framadate?

Tags: framadate

**Context**

Using https://framadate.org, I created a poll.

**Problem**

Someone has to edit his answer, but we don't find how. We thought to delete the answer and create a new answer, but same problem: we don't find how.

**Question**

How to edit or delete a question in a Framadate poll?

Comment: As poll admin, why can't I edit the poll to set answers edition possible?
And if I remember well, I let the users edit their answers when I created it... I'll redo one to see.

Comment: @pnuts I found where was the problem and answered my question, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found how to do it!

### TL;DR

You just have to click on the icons at the end of the line of your answer: [image]

### My problem

Because we had a lot of option, those icons was hidden, we had to scroll the whole line to see the icons.

Thanks to @pnuts, I tried with a smaller poll and saw the icons, so I searched them on my own poll and found them.